# Spring Cloud Config Vault does not work with the default profile

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-vault-config

I'm working on an implementation of config-server as per Manning's book [Spring microservices in action 2e](https://www.manning.com/books/spring-microservices-in-action-second-edition) and I encountered a problem that the config server doesn't read properties from the default profile.

My vault path is `secret/licensing-service/default`, I'm able to read the vault config for a default profile via this command

```
curl -X GET -H "X-Vault-Token:myroot" http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/data/licensing-service/default | jq
```

However when I enable debug logging and issue a request:

```
curl -X "GET" "http://localhost:8071/licensing-service/default" -H "X-Config-Token: myroot" | jq                    
{
  "name": "licensing-service",
  "profiles": [
    "default"
  ],
  "label": null,
  "version": null,
  "state": null,
  "propertySources": []
}
```

I see that spring tries to issue the following HTTP requests:

```
2022-11-13 15:41:41.272 DEBUG 92277 --- [nio-8071-exec-9] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate
              : HTTP GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/data/licensing-service
2022-11-13 15:41:42.100 DEBUG 92277 --- [nio-8071-exec-9] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate
              : HTTP GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/data/application
```

As can be seen it strips a default keyword from the URL, I found that it does so in the following class - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/main/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/environment/AbstractVaultEnvironmentRepository.java
In particular here:

```
private List<String> scrubProfiles(String[] profiles) {
        List<String> scrubbedProfiles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(profiles));
        scrubbedProfiles.remove("default");
        return scrubbedProfiles;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I make it read data from the default profile? Everything described above works for dev profile with vault path `secret/licensing-service/dev`
This is the config of my configuration server:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  profiles:
    active: vault
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          port: 8200
          host: 127.0.0.1
          kv-version: 2
          profile-separator: /


server:
  port: 8071
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and solved loading on VAULT the default properties in the
"application" (licensing-server in your case) path without trailing slash and default profile.
So on VAULT I have the path "application" for default values and "application/dev" for the dev profile